# tomcat localhost configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, localhost

How to configure tomcat so that a url may have a prefix to localhost (for example 'api.' so that is specified in the format:

http://api.localhost:8080/dirpath1/path2/path3/pathetc/?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to set up an entry in your `hosts` file. On linux/OSX, this file is located at `/etc/hosts`. On Windows it's typically located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. You'll want to open up the file in a text editor and add a line similar to this:

```
api.localhost    127.0.0.1
```

To set up a new application in tomcat for `api.localhost`, simply follow the [instructions for setting up a tomcat virtual host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html).